# How do you loop a spline in POV-Ray?

Tags: for-loop, spline, povray

Sigh! I wish this worked:

```
// Spline Sine
#declare SphereSine = union {
    #local Radius = 0.15;
    #local Amplitude = 2;
    #local Iterator = 0;
    #local Amount = 20;
    sphere_sweep {
        b_spline
        Amount,

        #for (Iterator, 0, Amount, 1)
            <Iterator, sin(Iterator)*Amplitude, 0>, Radius
        #end

        tolerance 0.1
        pigment {
            rgb <1, 0, 0>
        }
    }
}
```

Are there any ways to automate the adding of points to a spline in POV-Ray, so I don't have to add the points manually? Are there other alternatives?

Comment: It's POV-Ray, folks! It's LEGENDARY! :D

Answer (score 1):

You can write a macro of your own to wrap the `for` loop in and reduce the code to a single line of, say, `points(0.15, 2, 20);`. Otherwise, if you are looking for something like a built-in keyword for specifying the number of points or a point generation function, I'm afraid that there are no options available out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

sorry been too late ...

the problem is that you have put an amount of 20 but inside loop there are 21 values (0 to 20).

your solution really works !   just change

#for (Iterator, 0, Amount, 1)

with

#for (Iterator, 0, Amount-1, 1)

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please consider using the Stackoverflow Markdown for code. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more information

Comment: It's a few years ago now, but I distinctly remember this way of coding POV-Ray not working. Have you tested this pattern?

Comment: Kebman, do you refer to "#for (Iterator, 0, Amount-1, 1)" ?  it works in pov-Ray, sure.

Mike, I'll look Stackoverflow Markdown, thanks!